# Halmos's proof of Schröder-Bernstein theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

In the first paragraph of Halmos's proof of the Schröder-Bernstein theorem, he states:

> It is convenient to assume that the sets $X$ and $Y$ have no elements in common; if that's not true, we can so easily make it true that the added assumption involves no loss of generality.

I do not understand this point. How can we make it true?

As another question on this same theorem, a number of proofs I have seen talk about  successively applying $f$ and $g$, injections $A \to B$ and $B \to A$, respectively, to get functions of the form $(f \circ g)^n$. However, the Schröder-Bernstein theorem can apply to any sets, countable or not, so how is this not sacrificing generality and assuming that the infinities in question are countable? For example, this proof https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Schroeder-Bernstein_Theorem from the Art of Problem Solving website defines an element $b_1 \in B$ as a descendant of $b_0 \in B$ if $b_1 = (f \circ g)^n (b_0)$, but I may. have needed to apply $f$ and $g$ uncountably infinitely many times (can I even do that?) if there were uncountable many "lonely" points ($b \in B$ so that there is no $a \in A$ with $f(a) = b$.)

Comment: Informally I was thinking you could make it true by defining $X' = X \times \{c\}$ where $c$ is some element of $y$. Elements of $X$ would be in bijection with elements of $X'$ via $x \mapsto (x,c)$ but elements of $X'$ would not be elements of $y$ because - well, here's where I get lost. Maybe you need the axiom of regularity. Not sure. Some construction like this should work, irrespective of other axioms.

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary sets. To make them disjoint, you “paint” them different colors. Replace $X$ with $X\times\{1\}$, and $Y$ with $Y\times\{2\}$.

Comment: There is no assumption of countability of the sets. The construction associates elements that you can reach from one another in finitely many steps via applications of $f$ and $g$. There is no sacrifice. Imagine two copies of the natural numbers, green and purple, with purple numbers listed “after” green numbers. You don’t want to associate green numbers to purple ones because you can’t get for a green number to a purple one by moving one step at a time. You never get to purple points. So there is no need to talk about “infinitely many steps”.

Comment: In the constructions that look at $(f\circ g)^n$ (or $f^n$ and $g^n$), the number of iterations of the function(s) has nothing to do with the cardinalities of the sets involved. In particular, the argument at the AoS site is valid no matter how many ‘lonely’ points there are: nothing in that argument depends in any way on the cardinality of the set of ‘lonely points’. What part of the proof that $h$ is surjective do you think requires infinitely many iterations of $h$?

Comment: Most versions of the proof I've seen use a diagrammatic approach which requires enumerating both sets $A$ and $B$ and successively changing the arrows to apply $f \circ g$ a number of times, but in order for there to exist some $n$, it seems to me that the 'descendant' point has to $b_j$ for some natural number $j$, which requires countability. But if the set isn't countable, the enumeration fails.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I understand how that makes the new sets disjoint, but why does proving there exists a bijections between $X \times \{1\}$ and $Y \times \{2\}$ establish that there exists one between the original $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @StanleySmith: Because there is an obvious bijection between $X$ and $X\times\{1\}$. and one betgween $Y$ and $Y\times\{2\}$. Composition of bijections is a bijection.

Comment: “Diagramatic approach” is not a proof; it’s meant to help you visualize what is going on. There is no requirement of enumerating anything. For one element to be a descendant of another you need finitely many things in between and only finitely many things in between, but you do **not** need the whole ambient set to be countable.

Comment: This makes much more sense, thank you. One more question: would you mind explaining what you mean by "painting them different colors"? I'm not sure if this is a technical phrase or just an analogy.

Comment: It’s a metaphor. We “paint” $X$ with the color $1$ by making every element have a “sticker” labeled $1$ attached to it in $X\times\{1\}$. Similar for $Y$.

Comment: As an observation, I found the easiest route to follow for this was (1)  The Knaster-Tarski Fixed Point Theorem; (2) The Banach Decomposition Theorem (3) The Schröder-Bernstein theorem is then a trivial follow-on.