# A confusing proof-outline for the Schröder-Bernstein Theorem.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I have seen a number of  proofs of the much popular Schroder–Bernstein Theorem. But a particular proof outline interested me. My version of the Schroder–Bernstein Theorem is :

Assume there exists a  $1–1$ function $f : X → Y$ and another $1–1$ function $g : Y → X.$ Then there exists a $1–1,$ onto function $h : X → Y $

---

The proof outline was stated as follows:

(a) The range of $f$ is defined by $f(X) = \{y\in Y:y=f(x) \text{ for some} x ∈ X\}.$ Let $y ∈ f(X).$ (Because $f$ is not necessarily onto, the range $f(X)$ may not be all of $Y .$) Explain why there exists a unique $x ∈ X$ such that $f(x) = y.$  Now define $f ^{−1}(y) = x,$ and show that $f^{ −1}$ is a $1–1$ function from $f(X)$ onto $X.$ In a similar way, we can also define the $1–1$ function $g^{−1} : g(Y) → Y .$

(b) Let $x ∈ X$ be arbitrary. Let the chain $C_x$ be the set consisting of all elements of the form

$$(1) \space\space\space\space\space\space\space... ,f ^{−1}(g^{−1}(x)), g^{−1}(x), x, f(x), g(f(x)), f(g(f(x))),... .$$
Explain why the number of elements to the left of $x$ in the above chain may be zero, finite, or infinite.

(c) Show that any two chains are either identical or completely disjoint.

(d) Note that the terms of the chain in $(1)$ alternate between elements of $X$ and elements of $Y .$  Given a chain $C_x$, we want to focus on $C_x ∩Y $, which is just the part of the chain that sits in $Y .$ Define the set $A$ to be the union of all chains $C_x$ satisfying  $Cx ∩ Y ⊆ f(X).$  Let $B$ consist of the union of the remaining chains not in $A.$ Show that any chain contained in $B$ must be of the form $y, g(y), f(g(y)), g(f(g(y))),... ,$ where $y$ is an element of $Y$ that is not in $f(X).$

(e) Let $X_1 = A ∩ X, X_2 = B ∩ X, Y_1 = A ∩ Y ,$ and $Y_2 = B ∩ Y .$ Show that $f$ maps $X_1$ onto $Y_1$ and that $g$ maps $Y_2$ onto $X_2.$
Use this information to prove the existence of a bijective mapping from $X$ to $Y.$

---

However, I am facing some problems while proceeding with this proof-outline.

I could solve the claims in $a,b$ and $c.$

### Problem 1(Solved):

*Regarding this problem, currently I have no issues with this anyomore. Please check the other problem i.e, $\color{green}{\text{Problem 2 (Unsolved)}}$.*

But the problem lies with part $d.$

What I infered was, that :

> If $\exists C\in  B$ then, $\exists y\in Y$ and $y\in C$ such that $y\notin f(X)$. But we note that $g^{-1}(g(Y))=Y$ so, $y\in g^{-1}(g(Y))-f(X).$

I found the proof given for part $d.$ in the manual as :

> (d) Let $C$ by a chain in $B.$ Then $C\cap Y$ is not a subset of $f(X),$ so there exists $y\in Y$ with $y\in C$ but $y\notin f(X).$ Note that $C$ and $C_y$ have a point in common, so they must be equal.

But I feel that something has gone awry with the logic of the proof in the manual. This is only because, up until now, we defined chains only for the elements in $X$ and as $y\in Y(\implies y\notin X$) so, I don't understand what is meant by   $C_y.$

Further, if I am assume, that $C_y$ is the sequence $y, g(y), f(g(y)), g(f(g(y))),... ,$ where $y$ is an element of $Y$, there is still some problem. In part $b$ of the proof, we have proved either $C_x$ or $C_{x'}$ are completely disjoint or equal. I think, WLOG, we  can say that this assertion holds good for $C_y$ and $C_{y'}$ (where,$y,y'\in Y$) as well. But in *this* case (i.e in $d$ ) it seems that the author asserts the same thing to hold true for $C_x$ and $C_y$ (,where $x\in X,y\in Y$) which is, $C_x$ and $C_{y}$ are either completely disjoint (or $C_x\cap C_{y}=\phi$) or equal. But how can we say this, just like that, without a rigorous proof ?

---

### Problem 2(Unsolved):

The proof for for claim in part $d.$ of the proof outline, is given as:

Note that $Y_1\in f(X).$ To show $f : X_1\to Y_1$ is onto we pick a $y_1\in Y_1$
and show there exists $x_1 \in X_1$ with $f(x_1) = y_1.$ Well, if $y_1\in Y_1,$ we know there exists $x_1\in X$ such that $f(x_1) = y_1.$ But we must be sure that $x_1\in X_1.$ However, $C_{x_1}$ contains $y_1$ which is an element of some chain in $A.$ Since chains that intersect must be identical,  so, $C_{x_1}\subset A$ , and $x_1\in X_1.$

Now we have to show $g : Y_2\to X_2$ is onto. To do this, we pick $x_2\in X_2$
and show that there exists $y_2\in Y_2$ with $g(y_2) = x_2.$ Since $x_2\in X_2\subset  g(Y )$ we know there exists $y_2\in Y$ such that $g(y_2) = x_2.$ Now we need to show that $y_2\in B$ because if $y_2 \in Y$ and $y_2\in B$ then $y_2\in B \cup Y = Y_2.$ We know that $C_{x_2}$ contains $y_2$ which is an element of some chain $B.$ Since chains that intersect
are identical $C_{x_2} \subset B, y_2 \in B,$ and hence $y_2 \in Y_2.$

Finally, to prove $X$ and $Y$ has a bijection between them, define $h : X\to Y$ by
$$h(x) =f(x) \text{ if } x\in X_1$$
$$h(x)=g^{-1}(x) \text{ if } x\in X_2$$

Because $X = X_1\cup X_2$ and $f$ and $g^{-1}$ are $1–1$ and have disjoint ranges on these respective spaces, we get that $h$ is $1–1.$ Because $Y = Y_1\cup Y_2$  and $f$ and $g^{-1}$ are respectively onto, it follows that $h$ is onto as well. So, $h$ is a bijection.

---

But the thing that confuses me, is that:

(i) In the portion, where it proves, that $f:X_1\to Y_1$, how are they so sure, of the fact that $\forall x\in X_1$ ,$f(x)\in Y_1.$ I know that $Y_1\subset f(X)$ but it is never proved that $Y_1=f(X)$ till then ? It might happen for a particular $x\in X_1$ that, $f(x)\in f(X)-Y_1.$

(ii) In the portion where it proves, that $g:Y_2\to X_2,$ I have the same concern as in (i) above i.e how are they so sure, of the fact that $\forall y\in Y_2$ ,$g(y)\in X_2.$ I know that $X_2\subset g(Y_2)$ but it is never proved that $X_2=g(Y_2)$ till then ? It might happen for a particular $y\in Y_2$ that, $g(y)\in g(Y_2)-X_2.$

Any clarifications regarding this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $Y$ meets $X,$ just replace it by a copy of it which does not. Where does your proof come from? Didn't they write at the beginning something like "Assume wlog $X\cap Y=\varnothing$"?

Comment: @AnneBauval "Didn't they write at the beginning something like "Assume wlog $X\cap Y=\phi" ?" - The answer to this is no. They never mentioned it. It was written on a book called ,"Understanding Analysis " by S Abott, on pg-29. The solution was given in the manual written by the author. If you want, I can post the link of them as well.

Comment: Well the author was negligent and left that guess to the reader. As for your final "major point of concern", you just have 4 cases to consider, since $$[y=f(gf)^p(x)\lor y=g^{-1}(f^{-1}g^{-1})^p(x)]\land[y=f(gf)^q(x')\lor y=g^{-1}(f^{-1}g^{-1})^q(x')]$$ for some $p,q\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval But suppose we solve the whole problem by considering $A\cap B=\phi,$ then won't that be just a proof of a special case of Schröder-Bernstein Theorem? The Schroder-Bernstein theorem nowhere mentions that $A\cap B$ should be empty in it's statement , right ?

Comment: As hinted in my first comment, it is straightforward to derive the "general case" from the "special case". See for instance the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4068977)

Comment: @AnneBauval "As hinted in my first comment, it is straightforward to derive the "general case" from the "special case". " I take that the portion i.e "If $Y$ meets $X,$ just replace it by a copy of it which does not" is the one you are referring to. Ok, then say we did it, as you suggest and successfully prove the special case. But now, how do you extend this result to the general case?

Comment: Please follow the link in my previous comment. If there is a bijection between $Y$ and $Y'$ and a bijection between $X$ and $X'$, and injections $X\to Y$ and $Y\to X,$ then there are injections $X'\to Y'$ and $Y'\to X'$ hence (by the "special case" if $X'\cap Y'=\varnothing$) a bijection $X'\to Y'$ and therefore (by composition) a bijection $X\to Y.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Can you please explain, how are they asserting, "Equating the expressions for $ x$ and $x'$ and applying the appropriate combination of $f, g, f ^{-1}$ and $g^{-1},$  we can show that $x\in C_{x'}$ and $x'\in C_x.$" ?

Comment: Study the 4 cases mentionned in my 2nd comment above. In the 1st one, $y=f(gf)^p(x)=f(gf)^q(x'),$ if e.g. $p\ge q$ then $x'=(gf)^{p-q}(x)\in C_x$ and $x=(f^{-1}g
^{-1})^{p-q}(x')\in C_{x'}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval But it must be admitted, that this should've been mentioned in a clear way to avoid the confusion. Just one last thing, how do they finally conclude, $C_x=C_{x'}$ just from the fact that $x'\in C_x$ and $x\in C_{x'},$  just like that ?

Comment: Actually, only one of these 2 facts would clearly suffice: just from the definition of $C_x.$

Comment: @AnneBauval After giving it some more thought, I find it obvious now. Thanks!